# Python Pandas Multi Index - Count the number of occurrences greater than or equal to in tail

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

For each item, I would like to count the number of times in the last two periods the qty has been greater than or equal to 18.  The answer is written to a new df that has the item number and number of occurrences such as:

[image]

This is what I tried to do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'date':['2020-03-31','2020-06-30','2020-09-30','2021-04-15','2021-06-30','2021-06-30',],'warehouse':[10,11,12,13,14,15], 'qty':[16,17,18,19,20,21]}).set_index(['item','date'])
df

new_df = []
new_df['occurs'] = df['qty'].tail(2).ge(2).sum()
new_df
```

This produces an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why 3 gets NaN in your example, but this can be done by groupby and apply functions:

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:(x.tail(2).qty>=18).sum())
new_df
1    1
2    2
3    1
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used NaN for item 3 because there was only 1 item in the tail.  I thought that would force a NaN, but I am fine if the code produces the output you showed.

Comment: cool! don't forget to vote and mark as answered